# How to display error dialog for failed WixQuietExec CustomAction

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have following CustomAction which uses WixQuietExec to execute another application. If the action fails, the MSI installer doesn't pop-up any error dialogs which makes it hard for users to notice whether the installation completed successfully or not.

Is it possible to display an error dialog in such case? Honestly any standard error dialog will do, but custom error message would be even better.

```
    <SetProperty Id="MyAction"
                 Value="&quot;myprog.exe&&quot;"
                 Sequence="execute"
                 Before="MyAction" />
    <CustomAction Id="MyAction"
                  BinaryKey="WixCA"
                  DllEntry="WixQuietExec"
                  Impersonate="no"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="check" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="MyAction" After="InstallFiles" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Well it's called Wix*Quiet*Exec for a reason. You may try out [`WixShellExec`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/shellexec.html) custom action. [Usage example](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html). I've never used it but maybe it has error UI.

Answer (score 0):

What exit code does myprog.exe return when it fails?   You set return to check so if it returns a <0 exit code it should cause the installer to roll back and display the installation failed  dialog.  I wouldn't want a dialog at the moment of failure because if it ran for 10-15 minutes and then failed  you'd have 10-15 minutes of waiting for the rollback to finish.

Perhaps the real problem is that users aren't reading the last dialog to see if it finished or failed.